# Sound recorder for Linux

Tags: audio, microphones, audio-recording

I'm looking for recommendations for a good quality digital sound recorder.

Here are some requirements:

1. Small enough to be easily concealed. Preferably large enough to fit
   in a pocket.
2. Able to run wirelessly. Rechargeable batteries would be preferred,
   but they don't seem to be common with this type of device.
3. Has good quality recording, which is also not badly affected by
   surrounding noise. The usual way of handling this seems to be to
   have multiple microphones, but I don't care what method is used.
4. Able to record conversations on Android phones, preferably via
   internal connections to the phone
5. Able to record conversations in different standard formats, and at
   different levels of quality
6. Works well with Linux systems

Nice to haves include:

1. The ability to be used as a standalone microphone as well as a
   recorder
2. Durable. Can cope with being dropped, for example.

Note that I'm India, which limits available choices. But feel free to include options without regard to availability here.

I'm not too concerned about price, but anything more than say USD 200 will probably be too expensive for me.

I've been looking at the Zoom series of sound recorders, particularly the H1N. But I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: I note that you say "small enough to be easily concealed." I don't think that it's illegal to record a conversation to which one is party in India (it is in some other countries), but certainly some people might not take it well anyway.

Comment: I'm missing what the "for Linux" bit in the title means.